How to test smoke detector wiring
I have 14 hardwired interconnected smoke detectors in my house.  Assuming I have a hub and spoke topology, how can I determine which detectors are wired to which other detectors?
Ideally I would want half the detectors on each floor to be also wired to half the detectors on the other floor so that all floors get alarmed to some level if any detector alarms.

The interconnected systems I have seen are wired with /3 cable, so one of the wires provides the interconnect signal. In this way, you can easily test by disconnecting one cable at a time to see which detectors shut off (assuming you can remove the battery). If you can't remove the battery, you might have to test using the alarm and see which units don't go off - that would be unpleasantly loud.

Are they somehow not all on the same circuit?
